# Where to place the Settings for External *.dll to run VS code Locally

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am using an Azure Function I created with VS Code and added an external dependency (it's a Class Library created in VS 2022 *.dll). The External dependency requires me to have a connection string to an Azure SQL Server to work accordingly. I want it, to run locally to determine the outcome of the process, but I am unable to do it so.

I have added the dependency in the *.csproj as:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="HostServiceClassLib">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\HostServiceClassLib.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

### **What I did so far,**

In many places from VS Code, I added the settings namely `JksbMsSqlConnection`. Thus, so far included the following locations.

1. Folder > `local.Settings.json`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "JksbMsSqlConnection": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

2. Folder > vscode > `settings.json`

```
    {
      "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "bin/Release/net6.0/publish",
      "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "C#",
      "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
      "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "publish (functions)",
      "JksbMsSqlConnection": "xxxxxx"
    }
```

3. Folder > Properties > `launchSettings.json`

```
    {
      "profiles": {
        "CDSFileComposerFunc": {
          "commandName": "Project",
          "commandLineArgs": "--port xxx",
          "launchBrowser": false,
          "environmentVariables": {
            "JksbMsSqlConnection": "xxxxxx"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I even added the prefix as `SQLAZURECONNSTR_` but still no luck in all places above.

However, if I deploy to Azure and have the Settings under Azure Function > Configuration > Connection String it works!

[image]

My question is, for me to run it locally where do I need to place this connection string set? and what extra settings do I need to do?

Thank You,

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, for me to run it locally where do I need to place this connection string set? and what extra settings do I need to do?

You have to place the Connection strings in `local.settings.json` of the Azure Functions projects and that should be called in the C# Function Code.

I have taken sample code from the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup#add-a-timer-triggered-function) and used the similar syntax (connection strings) you have given in the Question:

**`local.settings.json`**:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "JksbMsSqlConnection": "Server=tcp:<server_name>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<db_Name>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<sqlserver_username>;Password=<server-password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
}
```

Call the SQL Connection String from the C# function code:

```
var str = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:JksbMsSqlConnection");
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Hari-Krishna Thank you for the post; was helpful. I have done what you said earlier and explained the same in my workings however, let me cross-check again if anything is being missed at my end. However, what comes to my mind is that the `*.dll` resides in a different directory and not in the same directory as in the project hence, should I have the `local.settings.json` file in the `*.dll` source directory instead? Let me revert back with an update.

Comment: `local.settings.json` is for running the Azure Functions locally, all the settings in that file should be added to the Azure Function App Configuration Settings.